# Richtig?: »Zu jung, um der Partei beigetreten gekonnt zu haben«

Tags: word-order, past

Ich habe gerade auf ein Facebook-Posting geantwortet, in dem die Nähe der FPÖ zur Hitlers Nazi-Ideologie diskutiert wird. (Aktueller Anlass: Ein Tiroler FPÖ-Funktionär hat vorgestern auf Facebook zu einem Foto von Adolf Hitler »Happy Birthday, Adolf« gepostet und hat in das Foto einen lustigen Partyhut und eine Geburtstagstorte mit Kerzen montiert.)

Ich habe in meinem Posting beschrieben, dass bis 1978 alle Parteiobmänner der FPÖ ehemalige NSDAP-Mitglieder und hohe SS-Offiziere waren.

Zum Wechsel auf den ersten Nicht-SS-Mann an der Spitze der FPÖ wollte ich schreiben, dass er aufgrund seines Alters nicht in der Lage war der NSDAP beizutreten, denn er war bei Kriegsende erst 17 Jahre alt.

Ich wollte diesen Sachverhalt wir folgt formulieren:

> Auf Friedrich Peter folgte als Parteichef Alexander Götz, der bei Kriegsende im Mai 1945 gerade erst 17 Jahre alt geworden ist, also zu jung um der NSDAP oder der SS ...

Wie geht's weiter?

- beitreten können gekonnt zu haben
- beigetreten gekonnt zu haben
- *(irgend etwas anderes?)*

Ich habe mich dann entscheiden für:

> ... zu jung um der NSDAP oder der SS beizutreten.

Da fehlt mir aber der Aspekt, dass er gar nicht gekonnt hatte, selbst wenn er gewollt hätte.

Wie müsste der unvollständige Satz grammatisch korrekt vervollständigt werden, um auch dieses Nicht-Können abzubilden, und wie schaut die grammatische Analyse eines korrekten Satzendes aus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Richtig wäre "zu jung, um der Partei beitreten gekonnt zu haben" - das Partizip zu 'beitreten' ist hier fehl an Platz. Es heißt ja "beitreten können". Und dies muss nun ins Perfekt gebracht werden.
Stilistisch ist deine einfachere Lösung natürlich besser; aber wenn man denn logischen Gehalt nicht verändern will (was deine Lösung ja tut), dann so.

Answer (score 4):

Dein Ansatz ist schon richtig - *zu jung, um beitreten zu können* und *zu jung, um beizutreten* ist jetzt semantisch nicht sooo weit auseinander.

Was mich mehr stört, ist die Zeitenfolge in deinem Satz (und ich glaube, das macht deinen Satz so verwirrend):

> ... folgte ... der ... geworden ist ...

Imperfekt und Perfekt - In deinem Satz tauchen aber *drei* Zeitpunkte auf, die mit Zeiten beglückt werden wollen:

1. er folgte - lang nach Kriegsende
2. Das Kriegsende selbst, nicht mit einem Verb versehen, aber eindeutig ein Zeitpunkt
3. Der 17. Geburtstag deines Protagonisten - Eindeutig vor Kriegsende, deswegen m.A. nach zwingend Plusquamperfekt, weil es vor etwas anderem, das in der Vergangenheit beendet worden ist, stattgefunden hat. Damit hört sich dein Satz mit "ist" an, als ob Kriegsende und Geburtstag auf den selben Tag gefallen wären (und ich glaube, das wolltest du nicht ausdrücken).

Der Satz sollte also eher lauten:

> ... dem folgte XXX, der aber 1945 gerade erst 17 geworden **war**, also zu jung [war], um beitreten zu können.

Und schon hört sich alles, finde ich, schlüssig an. Wie du siehst, habe ich das zweite "war" in eckige Klammern gesetzt, weil es eigentlich ein "weggelassenes doppeltes Verb" ist - zumindestens kann man es so betrachten. In deinen Zeitformen ist das ein "ist", und damit eindeutig die falsche Zeit - Ich glaube, auch deswegen hört es sich schräg an.

Wenn du unbedingt Perfekt nehmen willst, kannst du den Satz auch so formulieren:

> ... dem folgte XXX, der aber 1945 gerade erst 17 geworden, zu jung gewesen ist, um beitreten zu können.

Das löst zumindestens den Konflikt des "weggelassenen doppelten Verbs". *Ganz* richtig ist das meiner Meinung nach allerdings nicht. Es ist nicht sichtbar, dass die Zeitpunkte zeitlich auseinanderliegen.

Zur Auswahl des Modalverbs - Du und ich haben hier "können" genommen. Bei näherer Betrachtung wäre wohl "dürfen" richtiger. Die *Fähigkeit* einer Partei beizutreten, hat man theoretisch wahrscheinlich schon mit 17 (man muss schließlich nur eine Unterschrift leisten), nur nicht die *Erlaubnis*.

Was die Ansammlung von Modalverben angeht - Die kann man im Deutschen tatsächlich beliebig schachteln und zumindestens *grammatisch* ist ein Satz immer noch richtig - Aber spätestens beim zweiten Infinitiv  (muss einer sein, nur maximal ein Verb wird als Prädikat tatsächlich flektiert) wird es stilistisch gruslig.

> ... dem folgte XXX, der aber 1945 gerade erst 17 geworden war, also zu jung [war], um beitreten gekonnt zu haben.

Ist vollkommen richtiges Deutsch, weil es aber einfacher geht, wie im obigen Beispielsatz gezeigt, stilistisch unnötig kompliziert.

Nimmt man es noch genauer, muss das "beitreten Können" eigentlich ein Konjunktiv sein, denn es war ja nicht der Fall (Irrealis):

> ... dem folgte XXX, der aber 1945 gerade erst 17 geworden war, also zu jung war, als dass er überhaupt hätte beitreten können.

Ich habe auch noch ein bißchen Dekoration hinzugefügt, damit die Form klarer wird.

Comment: Das Plusquamperfekt habe ich absichtlich nicht verwendet, weil es in Österreich eher ungebräuchlich und hier nicht zwingend erforderlich ist. Aber du hast recht: Das würde den Satz vereinfachen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Auch in meinem Dialekt (und damit Sprachgebrauch) ist das Plusquamperfekt nicht gebräuchlich. Das es "nicht zwingend erforderlich" ist , stimme ich dir nicht zu. Ich glaube, das ist einer der Fälle, wo man wegen des "war" als weggelassenem gedoppelten Verb nicht darauf verzichten kann. Wenn du das "war" nach "jung" setzt, kannst du wohl auch Perfekt nehmen.